# RabbitMQ server not accessible from client network

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

We have implemented RabbitMQ on one the windows service application that will communicate to the server hosted on our production environment.

We have whitelisted our domain on the client network and also opened the port 5672 on our server.

This configuration works fine on one of the client network.

But on one another client network, it results in the following error

```
2018-03-22 13:53:35.0673  5  INFO   Starting service.    
2018-03-22 13:53:38.3566  4  ERROR   None of the specified endpoints were reachable Connection failed The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found    RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.TcpClientAdapter.BeginConnect(String host, Int32 port, AsyncCallback requestCallback, Object state)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler.Connect(ITcpClient socket, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Int32 timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IList`1 endpoints)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IList`1 endpoints, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IList`1 endpoints, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IList`1 hostnames, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
   at MessageQueue.RabittMQ.RabbitMQProperties.CreateConnection()
   at MessageQueue.RabittMQ.Consumer..ctor(String queueName)
   at MessageQueue.RegisterConsumer()
```

It is clear that the RabbitMQ client (windows service) is not able to establish connection with the RabbitMQ server hosted on our prod environment but not sure why and what could have caused this issue.

Do we also need to ensure the port 5672 be opened for IN and OUT bound connection in client network also?

We have used the domain name (test.server.com) as RabbiMQ host name to establish connection.

As the error says it is not able to resolve the DNS, do need to provide IP address instead of domain name?

Comment: You should at least _try_ to provide IP address instead of domain name. If that helps - you will know that issue is DNS and not something else.

Comment: @Evk But the same windows service with domain name is able to communicate with RabbitMQ server and works seamlessly on another client's network. So this error occurs only on this client's network.

Comment: Maybe, but that doesn't rule out DNS issue. This client network has it's own DNS server, different from other clients DNS server.

Comment: Please carefully read this document and follow the troubleshooting steps: https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-networking.html. A search on the text `The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found` indicates that your DNS is mis-configured and not returning data.